# Group items in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, split

Given this array:

```
@("abc", 5, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, "abc", 7, 9, 3, "abc", 3, 2, 4)
```

I'd like to end up with an array of arrays:

```
@("abc", 5, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4)
@("abc", 7, 9, 3)
@("abc", 3, 2, 4)
```

I.e. split the original array into groups each of which includes "abc" and the items that follow it up to the next "abc" or the end of the array.

Here's one way to do it:

```
$result = @("abc", 5, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, "abc", 7, 9, 3, "abc", 3, 2, 4)

$arrs = @()

$arr = @()

$result | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -eq 'abc') 
    { 
        if ($arr.Count -gt 0) { $arrs += , $arr }
        $arr = @() 
    }
    $arr += $_
}

$arrs += , $arr
```

Is there a more idiomatic way in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

```
$r = @("abc", 5, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, "abc", 7, 9, 3, "abc", 3, 2, 4) | 
       Foreach -Begin {$arr=$null} -Process {if ($_ -eq 'abc') {,$arr; $arr = @('abc')} else {$arr += @($_)}} -End {,$arr} | 
       Where {$_}
$r[0]
```

Outputs:

```
abc
5
4
2
7
6
5
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a slightly more idomatic approach, but it involved joining and splitting the arrays and strings a number of times, and this can affect performance negatively, as well as definitely being harder to read.

```
$result = @("abc", 5, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, "abc", 7, 9, 3, "abc", 3, 2, 4)
$arrays = $result -join "," -split "abc" | ? { $_ } | % {,($_ -split ",")}
```

This will only work if your data points NEVER deviate from `"abc",1,2,3` format.

We first join the entire array together with commas, then split out on your text delimiter, then discard any empty results.  If we don't discard, the split will give you an empty array based on the fact that there are n+1 pieces of a split array when split, even if the first item it finds is the split string.

Now we have n strings representing our data sets. Loop through those, split them on the comma to obtain your individual arrays.  for the example set you provided, this snippet would give:

```
@(5,4,2,7,6,5,4)
@(7,9,3)
@(3,2,4)
```

Now, if you want your text delimiter at the start of the array, change the command to this:

```
    $arrays = $result -join "," -split "abc" | ? { $_ } | % {,("abc" + $_ -split ",")}
```

Your mileage may vary, as I have only tested this on PowerShell 4, but I don't recall the performance of the `-split` and `-join` operators being different in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, the `"abc"` can be thought of as a delimiter. The grouping in the example occurs such that the delimiter is included at the *left* of the group. Here's function which is a little more general in that it accepts a predicate used to find a delimiter:

```
function Split-Array-Pred-Left ()
{
    param($in, $pred)

    $arrs = @()

    $arr = @()

    $in | ForEach-Object {
        if (& $pred $_) { $arrs += , $arr; $arr = @(); }
        $arr += $_
    }

    $arrs += , $arr

    $arrs
}
```

A similar function which includes the delimiter at the *right* of each group is the the same, but with two lines swapped:

```
function Split-Array-Pred-Right ()
{
    param($in, $pred)

    $arrs = @()

    $arr = @()

    $in | ForEach-Object {
        $arr += $_
        if (& $pred $_) { $arrs += , $arr; $arr = @(); }
    }

    $arrs += , $arr

    $arrs
}
```

Example:

```
PS C:\Users\dharmatech> $result = @(4, "abc", 1, 7, 5, "abc", 7, 2, 5, 4, "abc", 8, 7)

PS C:\Users\dharmatech> Split-Array-Pred-Left $result { param($elt) $elt -like 'abc' } | ForEach-Object { $_; '' }
4

abc
1
7
5

abc
7
2
5
4

abc
8
7


PS C:\Users\dharmatech> Split-Array-Pred-Right $result { param($elt) $elt -like 'abc' } | ForEach-Object { $_; '' }
4
abc

1
7
5
abc

7
2
5
4
abc

8
7
```